# ¿Cómo traer los datos de una tabla cuando falten 48 horas?

Tags: mysql

Buen día amigos, tengo la siguiente duda y es como puedo traer los datos de una tabla siempre y cuando falten 48 con la fecha que yo le pase, y con el campo de la tabla. Para ponerlos más en contexto consta de lo siguiente tenemos una tabla llamada eventos, y en esta tabla hay un campo fecha, que nos indica cuando inicia el evento, lo que yo quiero hacer es que le mando la fecha del servidor, para cuando falten 48 horas notificarle vía correo electrónico.

Use el siguiente código pero no me funcione como esperaba:
Para este ejemplo tenemos que el evento inicia el 10 de febrero, lo que queremos es que cuando falten 48 horas según la fecha que yo le pase me traiga ese resultado (cabe aclarar que si faltan más o menos de 48 no me deberá de traer ese registro)

```
SELECT ee.*
FROM events_events ee 
where ee.event_date_from > '2022-05-08' + interval 48 hour
```

Cualquier comentario con mucho gusto lo recibiré y espero que me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tengo un test que te puede ayudar con esto.**

Tengo una tabla llamada "dates" con esta información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asume que tu fecha de evento es "datetimeInit".

**Entonces hacemos lo siguiente:**

```
SELECT datetimeInit, now() as horaServer, 
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, now(), datetimeInit)) as secondsDiff
FROM dates;
```

**Donde:**

1. Con TIMESTAMPDIFF obtienes la diferencia entre las fechas que deseas, en este caso la fecha del registro y la fecha actual del sistema.
2. Con SEC_TO_TIME obtienes esa información en segundos, prácticamente como un cronometro en formato (hora:min:seg). Ejemplo (00:02:04)

**Entonces obtenemos lo siguiente:**

Con esto ya puedes tener un control de las horas que desees y que deseas validar. Por ejemplo si secondsDiff es menor o igual a 48:00:00 entonces ya deberías de enviar el correo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota:** La hora del server la simulo con la hora del sistema del ordenador, y las fechas del evento pues días futuros.

Espero te sea de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Agradezco bastante tu ayuda pero me surge la siguiente duda, y es como puedo condicionar la consulta con el valor creado "secondsDiff"; intente haciendolo de la siguiente manera:


SELECT ee.*,
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2022-05-09', ee.event_date_from)) as secondsDiff
FROM events_events ee
where secondsDiff = '48:00:00';

Aún así muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo ya pude condicionar la consulta, fuiste de gran ayuda, la forma en la que la condicione fue de la siguiente forma:



SELECT ee.*
FROM events_events ee
where SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2022-06-08', ee.event_date_from)) = '48:00:00';

Comment: En hora buena @JuanRincon, pero te sugiero que en la validación de fechas pongas <=, ya que puede que por 1 segundo consultes tarde y sean '47:59:59' y no te salte nada, entonces con el operador '<=' ya validas en caso de que la consulta se haya hecho segundos o minutos tardes.